# GSON Serializing JavaFx TablesView data source add key "helper"{"observable":{}}

Tags: java, serialization, javafx, gson

I created a program which contains a JavaFX TableView.
The datasource is a `observableArrayList<Users>` which is charged with json data. After the table showed the data and call the save procedure by serializing `observableArrayList <Utenti>` as follows:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Utenti>>(){}.getType(); 
 System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(observableListUsers,collectionType));
```

the output does a key **"helper": {"observable": {}}**
I'd like to understand the cause of this behavior and how to prevent that from happening.

this and the original structure:

```
[{"cognome":{"name":"","value":"ROSSI","valid":true},"nome":{...},"alias":{...}}]
```

and this is altered

```
[{"cognome":{"name":"","value":"ROSSI","valid":true,"helper":{"observable":{}}},"nome":{...},"alias":{...}}]
```

My class Utenti:

```
package sample.Model;


import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;


public class Utenti {



private SimpleStringProperty cognome;
private SimpleStringProperty nome;
private SimpleStringProperty alias;
private SimpleStringProperty mail;
private SimpleStringProperty nominativo;

public Utenti(String cognome, String nome, String alias, String mail) {
    this.cognome = new SimpleStringProperty(cognome);
    this.nome = new SimpleStringProperty(nome);
    this.alias = new SimpleStringProperty(alias);
    this.mail = new SimpleStringProperty(mail);
    }

public SimpleStringProperty getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public SimpleStringProperty getCognome() {
    return cognome;
}

public SimpleStringProperty getNominativo() { return nominativo; }


public SimpleStringProperty getAlias() {
    return alias;
}

public SimpleStringProperty getMail() {
    return mail;
}



public void setCognome(String cognome) {
    this.cognome.set(cognome);
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome.set(nome);
}

public void setAlias(String alias) {
    this.alias.set(alias);
}

public void setMail(String mail) {
    this.mail.set(mail);
}
```

**Edit: new code for duplicate problem**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

@FXML
TableView tw;
@FXML
TableColumn<User, String> colFirstname;
@FXML
TableColumn<User, String> colLastname;
@FXML
TableColumn<User, String> colAlias;
@FXML
TableColumn<User, String> colMail;
@FXML
TextArea taBefore;
@FXML
TextArea taAfter;
@FXML
Button btn;


private ObservableList<User> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    try {
        String content = new Scanner(new File("data.json")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(content).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray jsaUsers = (JsonArray) jsonObject.get("users");
        jsaUsers.forEach(user -> observableList.add(new Gson().fromJson(user,User.class)));

        colFirstname.setCellValueFactory(celldata -> celldata.getValue().getCognome());
        colLastname.setCellValueFactory(celldata -> celldata.getValue().getNome());
        colAlias.setCellValueFactory(celldata -> celldata.getValue().getAlias());
        colMail.setCellValueFactory(celldata -> celldata.getValue().getMail());

        tw.setItems(observableList);

        taBefore.setText("BEFORE CLICK\n"+new Gson().toJson(observableList));


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@FXML
void serializeIt(){
   taAfter.setText("AFTER CLICK\n"+new Gson().toJson(observableList));
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because you are serializing the objects that are probably not a very good choice for the serialization purposes. Why not just convert the observable list to a lightweight serialiazable list with simple DTO elements with `String` fields only? To load the data back, you could just get the serializable list and convert it to the observable list. The conversion is simple: Stream API, Google Guava, or anything else. Also, your JSON would be a few times lighter after dropping `SimpleStringProperty` internal properties.

Comment: I can tell you that the observableListArray serialization works very well with GSON. This phenomenon I observed only in the situation described in my question. Anyway thank you, I had already taken into consideration the solutions you suggested.

Comment: Technically, Gson works with fields only via reflection, and it may look "too deep" into a particular object structure that can be a subject to change from Java version to Java version thus making JSON documents incompatible between Java versions/implementations. Usually, it's much better not to serialize objects of unknown structure (that's encapsulated anyway) and use its public API in order to read its data and construct it back. For example, I couldn't reproduce `"helper": {"observable": {}}` locally probably due to different JavaFX implementation (or whatever could cause it).

Comment: Also note that you will get `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to javafx.collections.ObservableList` on deserialization since Gson is not aware of the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because Gson works via reflection and walks through all the fields in a particular object in order to generate JSON, and Gson fields iteration strategy applies over the field. In my opinion you might want to create special light-weight classes for your user entity (see Data Transfer Object pattern) and create *necessary* fields only that could be even annotated with Gson annotations like `@SeriailzedName` and `@Expose`. Converting between your entity observable lists and DTO lists is a trivial operation and can be implemented in many ways: Java 8 Streams API, Google Guava, Apache Collections (?), or your custom code after all. In this case you could control the strategy of transformation more precisely at the *call site* (I mean, where you use it).

Next, Gson is not aware of the `ObservableList` and its serialized JSON would be fine (since `ObservableList` is a `List` and `List` instances are well-known to Gson) just before deserialization where you'll get `ClassCastException` where you expect an `ObservableList` instance (Gson will deserialize it as an `ArrayList`). Regarding `SimpleStringProperty`: it looks like reflection plays fine here and the property objects can be deserialized back with success.

If you want not to deal with DTOs, you can configure Gson to work with JavaFx-related stuff.

First off, let's assume you have a simple entity named `FooBar`:

```java
final class FooBar {

    final SimpleStringProperty foo;
    final SimpleStringProperty bar;

    FooBar(final String foo, final String bar) {
        this.foo = new SimpleStringProperty(foo);
        this.bar = new SimpleStringProperty(bar);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("FooBar{")
                .append("foo=").append(foo)
                .append(", bar=").append(bar)
                .append('}')
                .toString();
    }

}
```

`ObservableStringValue` and its subclass `SimpleStringProperty` can have a special type adapter (`TypeAdapter<T>`) that would deal with the JSON stream forwards and backwards writing and reading your real objects. Note that `JsonSerializer<T>` and `JsonDeserializer<T>` are easier to use, but since they two require JSON tree objects in memory to work, type adapters are more efficient, especially if they are easy to implement (they can be very complex though).

```
final class ObservableStringValueTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<ObservableStringValue> {

    private static final TypeAdapter<ObservableStringValue> observableStringValueTypeAdapter = new ObservableStringValueTypeAdapter();

    private ObservableStringValueTypeAdapter() {
    }

    static TypeAdapter<ObservableStringValue> getObservableStringValueTypeAdapter() {
        return observableStringValueTypeAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final ObservableStringValue value)
            throws IOException {
        out.value(value.get());
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableStringValue read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        return new SimpleStringProperty(in.nextString());
    }

}
```

This type adapter takes any observable string value and writes it as a simple string rather than all the fields an `ObservableStringValue` instance may have (this is what you're getting with `name`, `value` and `valid`), but always converts strings to `SimpleStringProperty` due to lack of type info. The type info might be written as a part of an object though (fully qualified name, a special code representing the real type, etc), but I don't think you need it so far.

Next, the `ObservableListTypeAdapterFactory` implementation:

```java
final class ObservableListTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory observableListTypeAdapterFactory = new ObservableListTypeAdapterFactory();

    private ObservableListTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory getObservableListTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return observableListTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if ( ObservableList.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) typeToken.getType();
            final Class<?> elementClass = (Class<?>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            final TypeAdapter<?> elementTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(elementClass);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final TypeAdapter<T> objectObservableListTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) getObservableListTypeAdapter(elementTypeAdapter);
            return objectObservableListTypeAdapter;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

How it works: Gson uses type tokens to specify types precisely, and asks the factory if it can handle the type supplied with the type token. If not, then `null` is returned. In the implementation above, the very first check is checking if the given type is `ObservableList`, and then its element type is extracted from the parameterized type info, and then a new observable list type adapter is created and returned.

```java
final class ObservableListTypeAdapter<E>
        extends TypeAdapter<ObservableList<E>> {

    private final TypeAdapter<E> elementTypeAdapter;

    private ObservableListTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<E> elementTypeAdapter) {
        this.elementTypeAdapter = elementTypeAdapter;
    }

    static <E> TypeAdapter<ObservableList<E>> getObservableListTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<E> elementTypeAdapter) {
        return new ObservableListTypeAdapter<>(elementTypeAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final ObservableList<E> value)
            throws IOException {
        out.beginArray();
        for ( final E element : value ) {
            elementTypeAdapter.write(out, element);
        }
        out.endArray();
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<E> read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        final ObservableList<E> list = observableArrayList();
        in.beginArray();
        while ( in.peek() != END_ARRAY ) {
            list.add(elementTypeAdapter.read(in));
        }
        in.endArray();
        return list;
    }

}
```

This one is similar to `ObservableStringValueTypeAdapter` and deals with `ObservableList` instances and their respective arrays. Again, `TypeAdapter<T>` instead of `Json(De)Serializer<T>` here in order not to create an intermediate `JsonArray` saving memory and performance. It's a bit more complex because it generates and parses JSON arrays, but only for the `[` and `]` tokens: elements serialization is performed by the delegated `elementTypeAdapter` instance.

Now let's put it all together:

```java
public final class Q42210761 {

    private Q42210761() {
    }

    private static final Type fooBarObservableListType = new TypeToken<ObservableList<FooBar>>() {
    }.getType();

    private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(ObservableStringValue.class, getObservableStringValueTypeAdapter())
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getObservableListTypeAdapterFactory())
            .create();

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final ObservableList<FooBar> source = observableArrayList(
                new FooBar("foo-1", "bar-1"),
                new FooBar("foo-2", "bar-2"),
                new FooBar("foo-3", "bar-3")
        );
        out.println(source);
        final String json = gson.toJson(source, fooBarObservableListType);
        out.println(json);
        final ObservableList<?> destination = gson.fromJson(json, fooBarObservableListType);
        out.println(destination);
    }

}
```

Note how the `Gson` instance is configured above. And here is the effective output:

> [FooBar{foo=StringProperty [value: foo-1], bar=StringProperty [value: bar-1]}, FooBar{foo=StringProperty [value: foo-2], bar=StringProperty [value: bar-2]}, FooBar{foo=StringProperty [value: foo-3], bar=StringProperty [value: bar-3]}]
>
> [{"foo":"foo-1","bar":"bar-1"},{"foo":"foo-2","bar":"bar-2"},{"foo":"foo-3","bar":"bar-3"}]
>
> [FooBar{foo=StringProperty [value: foo-1], bar=StringProperty [value: bar-1]}, FooBar{foo=StringProperty [value: foo-2], bar=StringProperty [value: bar-2]}, FooBar{foo=StringProperty [value: foo-3], bar=StringProperty [value: bar-3]}]

Note that the JSON output is now much shorter, contains no other elements, and can be safely deserialized back.

Comment: Your explanation and clear and comprehensive Lyubomyr and I'll use it as inspiration in other circumstances. But do not you think it's strange behavior what I show in the code and related screen shots that I have entered now. No operation and made of ObservableList !!

Comment: @Bogojob Sorry but you have to inspect `SimpleStringProperty` yourself then. It's a sort of strange, I agree, but as I mentioned above it _might_ be an effect related to Java reflection (encapsulated anyway). In any case I would not  rely on non-public APIs especially for serialization purposes.

Comment: @Bogojob The `SimpleStringProperty` has a parent class `StringPropertyBase` that has `private ExpressionHelper<String> helper = null`. For some reason you have it instantiated. Again, this is not meant to be serialized.